# jQuery ajax call works only if its debugged step by step

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

```
        $('.single_add_to_cart_button').click(function() {
           $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: script_e.ajaxurl, //url loaded from the plugin 
           data: {id:test},
           cache: false,
           success:  function(data){
            alert(data);
           }
          });      
        });

   //php

   public function enqueue_scripts(){
      wp_enqueue_script( 'e_jquery', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'../assets/js/script_e.js' );
      wp_localize_script( 'e_jquery', 'script_e',
            array( 
              'ajaxurl' =>  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'event-capture.php'  ,
            )
      );
   }

   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'enqueue_scripts') );
```

I am trying to pass some variables in the the PHP script when the button is clicked, the php script is located in the plugin.

Only way this works is if I debug step by step in the firebug, then the value is passed, else it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically add `event.preventDefault();`after ajax call

Something like this,

```
$('.single_add_to_cart_button').click(function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: script_e.ajaxurl, //url loaded from the plugin 
    data: {id:test},
    cache: false,
    success:  function(data){
      alert(data);
    }
  });
  event.preventDefault();      
});
```